# Xamarin UWP app does not work

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using Visual Studio Update 3 + Update 3 patch. I created a Blank **XAML App(Xamarin.Forms Portable)** solution using the C# **Cross-Platform** Template. I checked off Build and Deploy in the Configuration Manager. I have updated the solution to Xamarin.Forms 2.3.2.127 (2.2 version had same issue). I have been able to run Android and iOS apps so far. I have made no changes to the source, I am using the empty project. When attempting to run the UWP app I get an error in **App.xaml.cs**:

```
Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e)


System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. 
   (Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.) ---> 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 
   Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.WindowsBasePlatformServices.GetAssemblies()
   at Xamarin.Forms.Registrar.RegisterAll(Type[] attrTypes)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(IActivatedEventArgs launchActivatedEventArgs, IEnumerable`1 rendererAssemblies)
   at Tester.UWP.App.OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): 
       Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try clean UWP Project and re-build.

Comment: I am using Blank XAML App(Xamarin.Forms Portable) solution using the C# Cross-Platform with no code added. UWP project fails at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e)

Comment: What target do you run?
Windows 10 Desktop
Windows 10 Emulator
Windows 10 Mobile Emulator
Windows 10 Mobile Phone

Comment: Windows 10 Desktop

Comment: Could you upload your sample project and let me try it on my PC?

Comment: Which zip file? I found has 3 zip files.

Comment: I have downloaded and check these 3 zip files, there is no any Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: 2nd attempt "App15.zip"
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj4PO87ZtwDcgrR5enQgA55gIYVtsA

Comment: The App15.zip project can run smoothly on my computer, so maybe your need check whether the UWP installation is completely.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 and click menu [File] > [New] > [Project] > [Visual C#] > [Windows] > [Blank App (Universal Windows) to create a new UWP Project, then check whether can run smoothly?

Comment: That works. The issue seems to be when the UWP tries to Init Xamarin: Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue when running Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 Enterprise 2015 LTSB as guest OS in VMware Fusion Version 8.5.0 (4352717). The host OS is OSX El Captitan 10.11.6.

Otherwise I had the same setup: Blank Xamarin project (Shared and Portable) with the exact same result when running the UWP project. Same happened with the TodoREST Example from the Xamarin website.

When debugging with VS, several 
System.InvalidCastException show up inside "this", "e" and "rootFrame" at the breakpoint at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e); i.e.:

```
    this.FocusVisualKind' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException
    at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW_WinRT(Object objSrc, IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget)\r\n   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.get_FocusVisualKind()"
    Message "Unable to cast object of type 'TodoREST.UWP.App' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.IApplication2'."
```

I tried several things

- update anything possible
- clean anything possible
- downgraded Xamarin in steps to 2.0
- re-install VS2015 Community from the Xamarin download site (including Xamarin 4.1)
- re-install VS2015 Community plain and Xamarin 4.2 afterwards

but nothing seems to have an impact on this exception.

Finally I went for a physical Windows 10 laptop and it worked like a charm.

So my best guess would be that the fact that Windows is running as Guest OS inside VMware has something to do with this error.

Since I already wasted way too much time on this, the only thing left I'm going to try is to update OSX to Sierra. Either it works or I'm going to stay with the "native" Windows workaround.

Comment: Update to Sierra did not change a thing.